# how to properly cacth awaitable method's exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, async-await

I have spent hours trying to figure it out (title). So I have two methods:

```
public virtual TEntity GetByName(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereName)
    {
        return this.DbEntitySet.FirstOrDefault(whereName);;
    }
```

and

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByNameAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereName)
    {
        try
        {                
            return await this.DbEntitySet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(whereName);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

the first method works as expected but the second one run ok if it is found but
entering a never ending process if it is not. I expect an exception will be thrown (possibly through `AggregateException`), even it is not throwing a TimeOutException. I tried to modified it like:

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByNameAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereName)
    {
        try
        {
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
            Task<TEntity> task = this.DbEntitySet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(whereName);
            if (!task.Wait(ts))
            {
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
            return await task;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

and then this method run ok `WITHOUT ANY exception`.
Any help please??

this is how I call this method(from begin)

```
//1
var activityManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ActivityManager<ActivityModels>>();
activityManager.CreateAsync(model).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
//2
public virtual async Task<WebCoreResult> CreateAsync(TActivity activity)
    {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();

        if ((object)activity == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.ActivityName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(activity));
        try
        {

            WebCoreResult result = await ActivityExistAsync(activity);
            if (result.Succeeded)
                return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        //code removed for brevity                
    }
//3
public async Task<WebCoreResult> ActivityExistAsync(TActivity activity)
    {
        var a = await FindByNameAsync(activity.ActivityName);
        //var a = FindByName(activity.ActivityName);    //this one ok

        if (a == null)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(new WebCoreResult("Activity not exist"));
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(WebCoreResult.Success);
    }
//4
public virtual async Task<TActivity> FindByNameAsync(string activityName)
    {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (activityName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(activityName));
        return (TActivity)await this._activityStore.FindByNameAsync(activityName);
    }
//5
public async Task<ActivityModels> FindByNameAsync(string name)
    {
        this.ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("activityname");
        }
        return await _activityStore.GetByNameAsync(x => x.ActivityName.ToLower() == name.ToLower());
    }
//6 finale: GetByNameAsync method above
```

Comment: Please add how you are calling `GetByNameAsync`. Also, `await FirstOrDefaultAsync` will **never** throw an AggregateException

Comment: please see updated question @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: Are you sure you're waiting the entire 5000 minutes to see the timeout in action? :p

Comment: ups my mistake @glenebob , thanks :)

Comment: This is pretty confusing. Do you want to know how to catch an exception, or how to cause an async method to timeout? Also, the async method that uses Task.Wait() will never run asynchronously.

Comment: If you're looking for timeout functionality, try the overload taking a CancellationToken: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.firstordefaultasync(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync%60%601(System.Linq.IQueryable{%60%600},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{%60%600,System.Boolean}},System.Threading.CancellationToken)

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i need to know how to catch an exception in async method, or may be i can ask, why I experienced the never ending Process instead of an exception?? (and how to get rid of it of course)

Comment: You have it about right for catching. As @CamiloTerevinto says, `await Task` will never (well, shouldn't anyway) throw AggregateException. Catching Exception should work. No idea why the routine does not return though.

Comment: Where is `//1` executed? I believe the problem is  a context switch deadlock

Comment: I am extending authorizeattribute filter. That &#39;//1&#39; part is in &#39;void onauthorize method. 
Could you point me to a good reference about context switch deadlock?

Comment: Your description indicates to me that there is something wrong with the way you call `GetByNameAsync`. Are there any `.Wait()` or `.Result` calls involved that cause the `await` to deadlock?

Comment: @Nitram I have included all codes related to this call.  The final method call  
this.DbEntitySet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(whereName) which is from System.Linq

I am happy to provide additional info if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by this line:

```
activityManager.CreateAsync(model).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

The call to `GetResult` forces the thread to block until the `Awaiter` completes. So you are blocking the main loop of ASP.NET. The problem now happens as soon as one `await` attempts to continue the execution. At this point it will schedule the continuation in the `SynchronizationContext` that is connected to the ASP.NET main thread. But this continuation is never executed, because the thread is blocked as the `GetResult`.

And that is how you likely created a deadlock.

There are some ways how to fix this.

1. Do not mix `await` with `Wait()` and `GetResult()`. If you use only one of both, you will be fine.
2. If you need to block a thread that is likely to have a `SynchronizationContext`, you need to ensure that the functions that use `await` are not trying to restore this context. The easiest way to do this, is to wrap the initial call into a `Task.Run(() => ...)`. That will work.
   You can find out if there is a `SynchronizationContext` in the current thread active, by querying `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current`. If is is `null` or a instance of `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext` you are fine. If it is any special implementation, you need to watch out.
3. You need to order the `await` calls to ignore the current `SynchronizationContext`. This can be done by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the awaitable objects. But you need to do this at least on every first `await` in every method involved.

Either one of these ways will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Nitram :D, I will try it as soon as I get back. Especially on number 2 and 3, because I Intentionally call this `async` method `Synchronously` (I want to write minimal methods, so i try to write one async method and use it for both async or sync call)

Comment: Thanks @Nitram,from now on,i will use ConfigureAwait(false) in most async await method unless i need the context :)